# How to autowire singleton inside session scoped bean

Tags: java, spring

I know I can autowire singleton (for example some service) into session scoped bean. The question is: does it store this singleton into HttpSession?

Comment: it will be the same way you autowire all other beans!

Comment: I know, but the session scoped bean is in HttpSession. Is this singleton serialized to session as well?

Comment: you need not worry about that.. the spring takes care of it for you . For every new session the same singleton instance (of service bean) would be made available to session scoped bean.